# Get Resource from HTTP and save to Iso Stoarage

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am currently using this code to save medai to isolated storage. This works frine if the media is local, but when I try to get medai from an http address I get error on URiKind. I have changed from Absolute. to Relative, but still no dice.

Any suggestions?

FYI - filename = http://www.domain.com/media.wma

Error: A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI.

Or: Expected relative Uri, found absolute.

```
private void DownloadToIsoStore(string fileName)
        {

            string ringtonePath = GetRingtonePath();

            IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            // If the file already exists, no need to "download", just return
            if (isoStore.FileExists(fileName))
            {
                return;
            }

            StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Relative));

            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(sr.Stream))
            {
                // Simulate "downloading" medai file
                byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)sr.Stream.Length);

                // Save to local isolated storage
                SaveToIsoStore(fileName, data);
            }

        }
```

Comment: What do you think Application.Get **Resource** Stream does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**U can use the following code**
1.Call this function with parameter (http://www.domain.com/media.wma)

```
    public void **GetMediaFile**(string httpPath)
    {
        WebClient wcMedia = new WebClient();
        wcMedia.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(httpPath));
        wcMedia.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wcMedia_OpenReadCompleted);
        wcMedia.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;

    }
```

2.Event Handler which downloads the media file to the desired(iso_path) location inside Isolated Storage.

```
    void wcMedia_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {       
        string iso_path="path where you want to put media file insode the isolated storage";
        var isolatedfile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(iso_path, System.IO.FileMode.Create, isolatedfile))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
            while (e.Result.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: Your buffer should not be so big, and you should only write the amount read.

Comment: Also, you should call `OpenReadAsyc` after adding the handler, in case it finishes too fast.

Answer (score 1):

`Application.GetResourceStream` takes a relative URI to a resource embedded in your application.
It isn't an HTTP client.

Instead, you should use the `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest` classes.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Any idea how I would implement a webclient into this code, or is it a re write?

Comment: I just rewrote with Webclient and its working fine. Thats for your help.